# Why do I get this error in my postfix/dovecot set up: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from?

Tags: postfix

Here is my main.cf:

```
myhostname = mail.mydomain.co.za
myorigin = mydomain.co.za
mydestination = mail.mydomain.co.za, mydomain.co.za, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/24 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.co.za/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.co.za/privkey.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3

local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination

maillog_file = /var/log/mail.log
```

and here is my master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

submission     inet     n    -    y    -    -    smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth

smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth

pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr

tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name

showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd


policyd-spf  unix  -       n       n       -       0       spawn
    user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/libexec/postfix/policyd-spf
```

Now I have tried it without "smtpd_recipient_restrictions" in main.cf,just in master.cf, but postfix gave an error. I tried it with "smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject" in both files and "smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination" still got the title error. I tried commenting "-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions" out in master.cf, but it doesn't help.

Please help, what can I do? I am new to this.

Comment: Your configuration shows relaying only allowed to either local submission, or authenticated submission via port 465 - if your mail is rejected, I'd assume what you are testing is simply not one of those permitted cases?

Comment: Quote the command you are using to test, and the entire log line stored by postfix, then it would be less ambiguous which service is rejecting what.

Comment: Could you elaborate.

Comment: So you are saying the issue is here: -o smtpd_relay_restrictions ?

Comment: Please tell us how you test, and the complete error message seen in the log file.

Comment: So what would I need to include, simply to have an email from the google server go through?

Comment: I am not using any command. I am simply sending the address emails from a gmail account.

Comment: Guys, after posting here with my real domain name, I've been flooded  with attempts to connect to my postfix, as though somebody is using a robot to do so. Please be warned not to post your real domain on here if you are new like me. And to the guy doing it: Please stop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clue on it being a relay problem. I changed smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject to smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination and it now works.